# Why does 张连跃 (2019) give the example sentence 我推荐你跟本地人一起住，这样可以事半功倍 to discuss problems with misused commonly/uncommonly-used words?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> 但也有相反的情况，即误用非常用词，当用词是常用词。例如：
>
> > （5）我**推荐**你跟本地人一起住，这样可以事半功倍。（当用“建议”）
>
> <sub>张连跃, *英语背景 CSL 学习者特异性混淆词语特征探析*, 2019.</sub>

The above paper analyzes Chinese words which are problematic for native-English speakers in particular.  The author lists 5 ways in which vocabulary can be misused, but I don't quite grasp the author's 5-th point above.

It seems to be pointing out that the students are using 非常用词 (uncommonly used words) as 常用词 (commonly used words).  However, the given example involves 推荐 vs. 建议, which I feel are both commonly used words.

**Question**: Why does 张连跃 (2019) give the example sentence 我推荐你跟本地人一起住，这样可以事半功倍 to discuss problems with misused commonly/uncommonly-used words?

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be paying attention to here.

Answer (score 2):

> 我推荐你跟本地人一起住，这样可以事半功倍。（当用“建议”）

推荐 - to recommend a suitable **person** for a position or for handling a particular situation.

- 我**推荐**"王小民"(a suitable person)和你一起住，这样可以事半功倍。

建议 - to suggest an **idea** or advise on methods/ways of handling a situation, which may or may not involve a person in the suggestion.

- 我**建议**你"跟本地人一起住" (an idea)，这样可以事半功倍。
- 我**建议**你"跟王小民一起住" (an idea)，这样可以事半功倍。

Answer (score 1):

Someone upvoted this [answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/42330/differences-between-%E6%8E%A8%E8%8D%90-and-%E5%BB%BA%E8%AE%AE/42331#42331) after this post appeared.

"推荐(recommend)你" is an incorrect choice of word in this context --   to 推荐 is to **push** for a **person**

"**建议** (suggest) 你跟本地人一起住 --> " is to **suggest** an **action**